# Equicontinuous and compactness

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, equicontinuity

[image]

Hello, everyone. I want to discuss about this theorem, which I read in "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Rudin, to enrich my knowledge about equicontinuity.
I think "equicontinuity" in the theorem means uniform equicontinuity, is it right?

Then, the theorem said "$K$ is a compact metric space", why it must be a compact metric space? What will happen if $K$ is not a compact metric space? Will it be equicontinuous at $x$ (not uniformly equicontinuous) if $K$ is not compact?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, equi-continuity means uniform equi-continuity.

Let $K$ be the real line with the usual metric, $f_n(x)=x^{2}+\frac 1 n$ and $f(x)=x^{2}$. The $f_n \to f$ uniformly but $(f_n)$ is not equi-continuous: In the inequality $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| <\epsilon$ for $|x-y| <\delta$ take $x=N+\delta /2$ and $y=N$. You will see that the inequality fails for large enough $N$.

Of course  equi-continuity at a point holds because a singleton set is compact.

Comment: Oh, I see. Compactness of $K$ is used to guarantee $f_n$ to be uniformly continuous.  Then, why $f_n$ must be uniformly continuous? Is it because $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly, so the $f_n$ must be uniformly continuous, so that we can get $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<3\varepsilon$ for $n> N$ and $d(x,y)<\delta$...?

Comment: Any continuous function on a compact metric  space is uniformly continuous. @MathLearner

Comment: @MathLearner In my [note](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/23.pdf) I showed in Lemma 1 that the pointwise version of equicontinuity (sometimes called "even continuity") coincides with the uniformly continuous version in compact metric spaces. This might help to give you context..